# Sqoop job fails on AWS with Connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqoop

I am executing the below sqoop command to get a table from another aws rds instance over to hdfs.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://awsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/financials_data \
--username someuser \
--password somepwd \
--table member_score \
--m 1 \
--target-dir /capstone/member_score
```

I could connect to this server using the workbench. 
But, sqoop fails to get the data.

The stack-trace is as shown below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-238 capstone]$ ./DataIngestion.txt
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
20/01/03 03:56:45 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.15.1
20/01/03 03:56:45 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
20/01/03 03:56:45 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
20/01/03 03:56:45 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
20/01/03 03:58:52 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
```

The stack-trace says connection error. But, I could connect using Mysql Workbench

Comment: Can you tell me where is your hadoop cluster? On prem or EMR ? If yes have you tried telnet ing rds from the cluster and also can you verify the security group configuration allowing traffic from the hadoop cluster?

Comment: Thank you for yorur respnse @bdcloud. The hdfs is on AWS EC2 as well. I am running the Cloudera VM on AWS. I tried to ssh the aws machine, but the connection timed out. But, colleagues are able to reach this machine. I have reviewed the security group settings and the port (3306) should be accessible.

Comment: The AWS RDS seems to be unreachable. See this : [ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-238 capstone]$ mysql -h upgradawsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u upgraduser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'upgradawsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-238 capstone]$

Comment: Can AWS be selectively unreachable from specific ec2 instances ?

Answer (score 0):

As sqoop was giving a Connection Error, I tried to ping the server.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-238 capstone]$ ping awsrds.cpclxrkdvwmz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
PING ec2-3-211-175-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com (3.211.175.82) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- ec2-3-211-175-82.compute-1.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
2935 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2934021ms
```

On seeing that server is not reachable, the next step to check was the `Security Groups` settings on AWS.

The outbound rule should allow `All Traffic`

[image]

I had previously set `Outbound` to specific IP. Since AWS allocates new IP each time static IP's dont work.